# Call a function with Timer at specific date

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nstimer, nsnotificationcenter

I need to call a function **5 minutes before midnight**.

The function is called only if the user is in the `UIView` containing a `UICollectionView` during that time period.

I need this collectionView to `reloadData()` **5 minutes before midnight**

I thought of using a `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver` observer

If you want to use `NotificationCenter` what would be the best way to receive the notification 5 minutes before midnight?

Do you think it would be better to use a **Timer** instead of an **observer**?

Which of these is more convenient for app performance?

thank you all for the help

Comment: Neither of these are possible if your app isn't running. Rather than doing something at 5 minutes before midnight, detect the first time the user is on your app after that, and do it then. It's observably identical

Comment: @Alexander- Reinstate Monica the app is running because I need to reload the collectionView only when the user is in front of the uiview that contains the collection view... the user is currently interacting with the app

Comment: Ah okay. Does this answer your question? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-at-a-specific-time

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Perfect.. Work !! Thanks Again!

Comment: You should write up your own answer and mark it as accepted. Or better yet, find a duplicate of your question and close yours as a duplicate. You weren't the first to ask this :p

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Yes you are right ... answer you so I accept your answer ... I think it is more correct :)

Comment: Eh, I don't have time to write it up now, and I don't have Xcode on this machine

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Ok ... I'll answer then ... :)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I can't accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

After reading **Alexander - Reinstate Monica** suggestion I found the solution to my problem using a Timer programmed for a specific date

```
let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(5)
let timer = Timer(fireAt: date, interval: 0, target: self, selector: #selector(runCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .common)
```

the solution is well explained here https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-at-a-specific-time